# Show that $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ be compact such that $a \in X$ and $b \in Y$. If $X - $ {$a$} is homeomorphic to $Y - $ {$b$}, show that $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic.

Things I've thought of using:

$(*)$ $X \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$. We say that $X$ is compact if it is closed and bounded.

$(*)$ Let $f:X \subseteq \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow Y \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ bijective and continuous. If $f^{-1}: Y \rightarrow X$ is continuous, then it is called a homeomorphism of $X$ over $Y$.

$(*)$ Let $K \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ be compact. Then every continuous injective function $f: K \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ is a homeomorphism on $f(K)$

Could someone help me that I don't have much idea how to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the way to go about this is pretty straightforward.
Suppose $g: X\setminus\{a\} \longrightarrow Y\setminus\{b\}$ is a homeomorphism, and define $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ by $f = g$ on $X\setminus\{a\}$ and $f(a)= b$.

Clearly, $f$ is injective and $f(X) = Y$.
Can you show that $f$ is continuous?
If you can, then you may apply your third point to conclude that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: I understand your idea well but it is not clear to show that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Your third point requires that $K $ be compact.

Comment: Yes, of course, I read correctly, I must prove that X and Y are homeomorphic, so I must use it is the second proposal that I had thought

Comment: because in the third point I would have that $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$ is homeomorphic but I must prove that $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The third point means $K$ and $f(K)$ are homeomorphic. In my proposed solution, $K=X$ and $f(X) = Y$.

Comment: ohh ok I understand, so if I was confused and I just have to prove that $f$ is continuous

Comment: Yes, you must prove that $f$ is continuous (and, invoking the third point, explain why that solves the problem).

Comment: ok, ok then to prove that $f$ is continuous, I take a sequence $(x_ {k}) \subseteq \mathbb {R^n} $ such that $ \lim x_{k} = a$, then the $\lim f(x_{k}) = f(a)$ and so $f$ is continuous in $a$. Would it be like this?

Comment: There are many ways to prove continuity. It seems you are using the sequential continuity definition. You would need to *prove* that $f(x_k)$ converges to $f(a)$.